# Change page in php - repeat html tags?

Tags: php, html

I'm learning php and I have a very simple question. I'm not sure how should I handle "multiple pages" in my web site.

Minimal example, index.php:

```
<html>
    <head>
      <title>PHP example</title>
      <link rel="...">
      <script src="..."></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        ...
        <input type="button" value="View" onClick="window.location='view.php';" />
        ...
    </body>
</html>
```

As far as I understand when the user click the button, the browser will be redirected to "view.php" - Hence that page should be a complete html page, like index.php is (with all the relevant tags).

**Is it correct to repeat all the html tags in the new page?**

I'm not talking about to replace the content of a div, like in a menu structure where each item lead to the related content (single-page application).
In this case I really (?) need to "replace" the whole body content, so I wonder if it's correct to just create another complete html page.

Comment: The more common approach is to have any shared elements (header, footer, etc) in their own files, which you then pull into the pages themselves using `include`, or similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes that is the right approach, you need to create pages for each and every of your request. Until you are not using any CMS or routing to get the content from the database for every request.

There are many different frameworks in php, and they handle requests in many different ways.

But the way you are designing the site, in this you will have to create the pages for each and every request. What you can do is you can create a common file and require_once that for the common elements like header and footer(or left/right sidebars, if any).